# Script shell for renaming and rearranging files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to rearrange and rename files.
I have this tree structure of files :

```
ada/rda/0.05/alpha1_freeSurface.md
ada/rda/0.05/p_freeSurface.md
ada/rda/0.05/U_freeSurface.md
ada/rda/0.1/alpha1_freeSurface.md
ada/rda/0.1/p_freeSurface.md
ada/rda/0.1/U_freeSurface.md
```

I want that files  will be renamed and rearranged like this structure below:

```
ada/rda/ada-0.05-alpha1.md
ada/rda/ada-0.05-p.md
ada/rda/ada-0.05-U.md
ada/rda/ada-0.1-alpha1.md
ada/rda/ada-0.1-p.md
ada/rda/ada-0.1-U.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the perl `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) utility:

```
rename  's|ada/rda/([^/]*)/([^_]*).*|ada/rda/ada-$1-$2.md|' ada/rda/*/*
```

(Note: by default, some distributions install a `rename` command from the `util-linux` package.  This command is **incompatible**.  If you have such a distribution, see if the perl version is available under the name `prename`.)

#### How it works

`rename` takes a perl commands as an argument.  Here the argument consists of a single substitute command.  The new name for the file is found from applying the substitute command to the old name.  This allows us not only to give the file a new name but also a new directory as above.

In more detail, the substitute command looks like `s|old|new|`.  In our case, `old` is `ada/rda/([^/]*)/([^_]*).*`.  This captures the number in group 1 and the beginning of the filename (the part before the first `_`) in group 2.  The `new` part is `ada/rda/ada-$1-$2.md`.  This creates the new file name using the two captured groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename` and `dirname` functions to reconstruct the new filename:

```
get_new_name()
{
    oldname=$1
    prefix=$(basename $oldname _freeSurface.md)
    dname=$(dirname $oldname)
    basedir=$(dirname $dname)
    dname=$(basename $dname)
    echo "$basedir/ada-$dname-$prefix.md"
}
```

e.g. `get_new_name("ada/rda/0.05/alpha1_freeSurface.md")` will show `ada/rda/ada-0.05-alpha1.md` in console.

Then, you can loop through all your files and use `mv` command to rename the files.